# Creating a measure to count the non-blank cells in a matrix

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I have a data table of how many passengers get on and off a bus. It records which section they got on and which one they got off. My table looks like this:

```
SectionIn  SectionOut  Pax
--------------------------
1          1           1
1          1           2
1          3           3
1          1           1
1          3           5
...etc...
```

With this data, I created a matrix with `SectionIn` on rows, `SectionOut` on columns, and the sum of `Pax` as the value.

[image: Example matrix (more in the file)]

First (and most important) I need to count how many instances you have in the matrix. That is, how many cells in the matrix have a value. In this case, I have 15 instances (1+2+3+4+5 values in the upper triangle). In Excel, it is easy with the `COUNT` formula (check the file please), but not dynamic.

Then, I need to calculate % of the grand total with filters and no filters (I think we have to considerate the evaluation context here). This are less important because they depend on the **magic counting measure** above.

Here you can find a sample database with a pivot table and the target I'm looking for. I created the target with Excel formulas but I need that in DAX so I can dynamically filter the pivot table and get the result in another pivot table.

Sample test: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xtNdM7g8lWHvqF8UX4K3TP0uOp-fFIZ5/view?usp=sharing

I found easier using examples in that file than explaining with words what I need (hopefully you too), but if you don't understand please don't hesitate asking anything.

Thank very much in advance!

Regards,

Andy

Comment: It's not clear from the text what your question is. Sharing a file is very helpful but what you're asking needs to clear without downloading a file.

Comment: Hi Alexis! Thank you for replying, but it is a bit difficult to write down what I need. I mean, I don't want to write a book here and then you will use the file because it is too long (where I think it is clear). Please, give it a try! If it is a policy of the site I can describe everthing.

Comment: It's reasonably clear from your examples, but [site policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) states "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.**... Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text." If you can turn one of your examples into a [minimal workable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I'd be happy to answer.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Alexis! I'm new into this kind of posts. I will modified the text.

Comment: Hi Alexis, please check it now if it is more clear the description. I used an image so you can see the structure of the matrix where I need to perform the calculations. There are more examples in the file. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a summary table that lists each combination of `SectionIn` and `SectionOut` and then count the number of rows in that table. It would be just like your pivot table but with both on rows and look like this:

[image: Summary table]

Here is the DAX code to do that:

```
CellCount =
COUNTROWS (
    SUMMARIZE (
        ALLSELECTED ( InOut ),
        InOut[SectionIn],
        InOut[SectionOut],
        "Passengers", SUM ( InOut[Pax] )
    )
)
```

(Note: You don't even need the `"Passengers", SUM ( InOut[Pax] )` line for the measure to work.)

This is indeed dynamic as demonstrated here:

[image: Final Analysis]

Comment: I tried it and it is amazing!! I could never have reached to that measure... The SUMMARIZE function is my nemesis... Still don't understand it. Thank you very very much Alexis!!

Comment: If you're familiar with SQL, it's analogous to `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Yes. DAX also has a [`GROUPBY` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/groupby-function-dax) you could use instead of `SUMMARIZE`.

Comment: That's insteresting. Can I ask also how to count the non-blank cells global for each track? It was also necesary for my analysis. In that example you selected sections 4 to 7. I need also the total of the track no matter the filters I apply. I tried with ALLEXCEPT instead of ALLSELECTED but it doesn't work (let me know if this requeries an additional post). Thanks again!

Comment: For a total ignoring filters, use `ALL` rather than `ALLSELECTED`.

Comment: Yes, but I need the total of the track. **Ignore all filters, except the track one.** That's why I tried with `ALLEXCEPT`, but I'm thinking it has a different behaviour because it is working as I have used `ALL`.

Comment: You can either use `ALL` with a list of columns you want to remove filters on or `ALLEXCEPT` with a list of columns you want to keep filters on.

Comment: Yeap, I tried exactly as you said (`ALL` and `ALLEXCEPT`) and it only calculate the grand total with no filters. I updated the file so you can check it. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I think you may need to write a new question.

Comment: Absolutely. Thank you very much!! People in this community make the world better :)